# How to properly write an equation for counting number of times a threshold is exceeded?

Tags: summation, notation, education

Basically, I have a function, and if it exceeds a threshold, I want to increment my value by 1. I want to write this mathematically, and I feel it should look something like this

$$y = \sum_i x'_i-x_i > \gamma$$

but this seems sloppy. Basically, $y$ is the number of times that $x'_i -x_i > \gamma$. Is there a way to use the delta function to make this look cleaner?

Comment: [$\sum_{i}\mathbb{1}_{\{x'_i-x_i>\gamma\}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)?

Comment: You can just write it as $\sum_i [ x_i' - x_i > \gamma ]$ and tell people you are using [Iversion bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).